# How to include Json string in uri c# 6

Tags: c#, json, url, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a c# object: a list with objects (objects have ID and Name)

Now I need to include the list of objects (it should be json string as far as I understand) in URL as parameter. How is it possible to do it?

Comment: Please, be more specific. Where do you want to include that? In your request body? As part of the query string parameters? In a razor view by using Action or Url Link? In your javascript by using a post request with jQuery?...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need this.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
string response = client.UploadString("http://mysite", "json string");
```